# Value for Terraform Composer airflow_config_override secrets-backend_kwargs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to change, using Terraform, the default [project_id](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/secret-manager) in my Composer environment so that I can access secrets from another project. To do so, according to Terraform, I need the variable [airflow_config_overrides](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/composer_environment#airflow_config_overrides). I guess I should have something like this:

```
resource "google_composer_environment" "test" {
  # ...

  config {
    software_config {
      airflow_config_overrides = {
        secrets-backend = "airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend",
        secrets-backend_kwargs = {"project_id":"9999999999999"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The secrets-backend section-key seems to be working. On the other hand, secrets-backend_kwargs is returning the following error:

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "airflow_config_overrides": element "secrets-backend_kwargs": string required
```

It seems that the problem is that GCP expects a JSON format and Terraform requires a string. How can I get Terraform to provide it in the format needed?

Comment: What happens if you wrap it with `jsonencode()`?

Comment: Yeap, `jsonencode()` worked just fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a map such as `{"project_id":"9999999999999"}` into a JSON encoded string by using the [`jsonencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html).

So merging the example given in the [`google_composer_environment` resource documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/composer_environment#airflow_config_overrides) with your config in the question you can do something like this:

```
resource "google_composer_environment" "test" {
  name   = "mycomposer"
  region = "us-central1"

  config {
    software_config {
      airflow_config_overrides = {
        secrets-backend = "airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend",
        secrets-backend_kwargs = jsonencode({"project_id":"9999999999999"})
      }

      pypi_packages = {
        numpy = ""
        scipy = "==1.1.0"
      }

      env_variables = {
        FOO = "bar"
      }
    }
  }
}
```